# Form designer has became unavailable for a form in Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, designer

After some work on form in Visual Studio 2015, form designer suddenly became unavailable.

Symptoms:

- item **View Designer** is missing from context menu of form code class in Solution Explorer
- usual keyboard shortcut cannot be used to switch to the designer
- **.Designer** and **.resx** files are still in place and correctly shown as subtree items of form code class
- **.Designer** and **.resx** files look healthy from inside, they have every mandatory part
- Visual Studio reports **0 errors**
- only one form is affected, other can be open in the designer normally

Why the Visual Studio is not evaluating form files as valid, not showing Designer view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Fix:** In source code of the form, manually move any classes ***below*** the class which defines the form. The form class must be the first class definition encountered when reading the source file from top to bottom.

**Details:**

I accidentally locked myself out, with error message written behind the locked door.

**Issue:** During the work, I temporarily added a trivial helper class to the beginning of the form code file. **If** I had the designer open that time, I could have seen the following error:

> The class Form1 can be designed, but is not the first class in the file.  Visual Studio requires that designers use the first class in the file.  Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try loading the designer again.

The catch is, ***the error shows only in the designer. If you have only code window open at the moment, you won't spot the error – and worse, you are no more allowed to enter the designer view to discover it.***

So a case can happen, when Visual Studio gives no clue – the only help is qualified guess and trial.

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck on it !

Comment: Thanks, works great. Silly problem to affect so much.

Comment: How did you fix the issue?

Comment: @JayElston - by manually editing the source code: making the form class first again. Any other classes can be only on lines below that class.

Answer (score 1):

in case anyone else needs a different fix, i had the same issue but it was with telerik reports.

not sure why or how, but my issue was a corrupted project file. The subtype element was missing for the reports. This element tells visual studio to use a designer template to open the file, instead of code view.

the subtype depends on what type of control it is. For a windows form the subtype would be **Form**

unload the project -> right click -> edit ".csproj"

so i changed this (in the project file):

```
<Compile Include="Report1.cs" />
<Compile Include="Report1.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Report1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

to this:

```
<Compile Include="Report1.cs">
  <SubType>Component</SubType> <!-- if winform, this would be Form instead -->
</Compile>
<Compile Include="Report1.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Report1.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

Just add existing designer of the form from the directory to solve the problem.
After adding the existing file in visual studio the context menu for **'view designer'** is showing.

[image: visual studio view designer not showing case]