# Form will not open in designer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Sometimes, I have a form in the solution explorer that will not show the form icon but a plain class file and clicking it will open the code.

There is no way to enter the form designer.

How do I repair it? Is it broken? The program still builds and runs.

[image]

Comment: There's not much definitive we can say based on so little information but, most likely, you have changed the type name in one of the code files or something like that. You should compare both the user code file and designer code file for that form to the code files for a different form and see what's different between them. If it is the type name then don't change it in code. Change the item name in the Solution Explorer and then VS will prompt you to change the class name automatically in all the appropriate places.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Form designer has became unavailable for a form in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31891299/form-designer-has-became-unavailable-for-a-form-in-visual-studio)

Comment: No, but I had another solution, so this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by

- Copying the three files (.vb, .designer.vb, .resx) to a backup location
- Removed them from visual studios Solution explorer.
- I added a form with the same name using Add → New Item.
- I copied the old files back over the newly created ones in explorer.

Now, the icon still shows that it is a form and I can open the form designer again.

Note that no file was altered in the project using this solution.

If anyone could tell me where the change actually happened, please let me know.